# Exit Codes when using die in Perl

Tags: perl, error-handling, die

I have overridden `die` in perl for my logging framework, so that it can log messages and print it on console.

**Overridden code for die:**

```
BEGIN{ *CORE::GLOBAL::die = sub { 
        my ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine) = caller;
        untie *STDERR;
        my $message;
        foreach my $arg (@_) {
            $message = $message.$arg;
        }

        print STDERR $message;
        tie *STDERR, __PACKAGE__, (*STDERR);
        logmessage("die",$message,$filename, $line);
        #What exit code to pass?
        #exit CODE;
    }
}
```

I don't know what exit code to set while exiting the process as the normal die exits with an error code.

- Is there any way I can find out what exit code to set when die is
  called?
- Also It would be helpful if can know the list of error codes availabe
  in perl?

Comment: Note that `die()` just throws an exception that can be caught later with `eval { ... }`. A `die()` should not directly terminate the program!

Comment: Sidenote: see also if [`$SIG{__DIE__}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25SIG) could suit your needs.

Comment: Ok i will check that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exit code is documented in [die](http://p3rl.org/die):

> ```
>  exit $! if $!;              # errno
>  exit $? >> 8 if $? >> 8;    # child exit status
>  exit 255;                   # last resort
> ```

But as @amon noted, `die` doesn't exit, it throws an exception. Instead of overriding it, it might be clearer to wrap the whole thing into an `eval { ... ; 1 }` (or [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try::Tiny)'s `try`) and log the exception in the `or do` or `catch` part.

Comment: Since die is overridden what exception to throw from my die?

Comment: It starts with "instead of overriding", so there's no "my die".

Comment: problem is my project has already 300 perl files and I cant wrap each and everywhere in all those files. So i need to override it if i want log messages into my logging framework

Comment: Then `$SIG{__DIE__}` might be more suitable.

Comment: Do you have 300 scripts that call each other? Or just few scripts and lots of `.pm` modules?

Comment: 300 scripts and some 50 modules

Comment: You have my sympathies.

Comment: Ha ha so there is no way is it? I just have to follow my old implementation?

Comment: You can use `$SIG_{__DIE__}`. But please, put the code into a single module and load it from all the scripts instead of inserting the code into each of them.

Answer (score -2):

`die()` exits with a none-zero exit code (but it's not defined, which, I believe):

```
jan@jancooltek ~ $ perl
die("test");
test at - line 1.
jan@jancooltek ~ $ echo $?
9
```

However, with -e:

```
jan@jancooltek ~ $ perl -e 'die("test")'
test at -e line 1.
jan@jancooltek ~ $ echo $?
255
```

`exit()` can use any exit code you'd like, there are no specific rules in Perl.
Settle on something != 0 and use that for these generic errors.